# Typescript Strict Null Checks on Objects With optional keys

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

I am introducing the `strictNullchecks` compiler option in our Angular project and have come across this issue.

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

```js
  replaceTokens(menuItemList: MenuItem[]): MenuItem[] {
        for (let i = 0; i < menuItemList.length; i++) {
            if (menuItemList[i].route) {
                menuItemList[i].route = this.tokenizer.replace(
                    menuItemList[i].route <-- Error here
                    // menuItemList[i].route as string <-- No error here
                );
            }
        }
        return menuItemList;
    }
```

In the code above I am checking that `menuItemList[i].route` is defined before using it, however I am still getting the error outlined above.

If I were to cast it to a `string` then it would solve the issue, but I think that is a bad work around as i've already confirmed that it can't be `undefined` in the if statement so it **must** be the `string` type.

I believe the issue could be to do with the fact that `MenuItem.route?` is optional, but can't see why that's a problem as I have previously mentioned it can't be `undefined` due to the `if` check.

Comment: Use a local variable for `menuItemList[i]` and control flow should be able to follow the
 check

Comment: Do you think there is a way to do this without resorting to that? Also, why does your solution work?

Comment: This is a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28081) and it should hopefully be [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31478) for TS3.6.

Comment: @jcalz I'm not sure how that bug is related? My code works the same using `['value']` or `.value`